# Bypass PHP timeouts

Tags: php, redirect, timeout

How is it possible, to relieably bypass any timeouts imposed by a server or browser? On many managed hosting servers even `set_time_limit(x)` and `ini_set('max_execution_time', x)` are overwritten and limited to usually a few minutes.

Splitting the workload between multiple files and redirecting to the next one would be one possibility, however Google Chorme for example aborts after 20 redirects.

Are there any other ways to prevent a premature exit of the script?

I know StackOverflow doesn't like these kind of questions very much, but there aren't any comparable help websites that do.

Thank you very much

Comment: browser does not have any timeouts. it will wait forever and ever. there is nothing that you can do to avoid timeouts on server They are designed to prevent resource hogging processes. You can work around them, by accepting jobs, putting them into queue, processing them using some background process and storing result in database then showing user result when it is ready.

Comment: Do you need to do it from the browser? From the command line using a task scheduler like cron seems a better solution based on the little information you have provided.

Comment: `managed hosting servers` Thats a business, so you have to pay for more resources. But you are talking about `redirecting`, but is it maybe possible to do a background job? like `shell_exec('ab.php >> log.log 2>&1 &');` or else?

Comment: You should question your architecture if you need to operate long running processes from a browser. That is not what the web is made for.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve. For example, I had this kind of issue while handling a lot of heavy files on server and sending them to the client archived, so I've implemented offsets specified by client-side AJAX script. Here's what I ended up with: https://github.com/stmswitcher/ajax-grabber

Answer (score 0):

Run your PHP script through AJAX iterations via `setInterval()`. Adjust your PHP script to run manageable batches for each iteration.